# Remove asp button background?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

In my modal header, I need the x button to do some serverside work, so it needs to be an asp button.

I have both here:

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        ×</button>
   <asp:Button ID="btnX" CssClass="close no-bg" runat="server" Text="×" 
          OnClientClick="closeModal('#projectModal')"  
          OnClick="btnClose_Click" aria-hidden="true" />
   <h3 id="projectModalLabel">Edit Project</h3>
</div>
```

However, my asp button still looks like a button while the other html button with boostrap close style looks correct just displaying an 'x'.

How can I make the asp button look like the html one (eg remove background)

Thanks

Comment: Please show the actual HTML + CSS, not you .NET server-side code.

Comment: Ummmmmm this is html...

Comment: I think @Kaf means the generated HTML that your ASP produces

Comment: Sorry "asp:Button" is .NET, not HTML.

Comment: The CSS is just boostrap close, it has nothing to remove background, just I think text-decoration none but I tried several styles that did not work.

Comment: @JasonSperske, it wasn't me, I just edited the question. :). Anyway, your ASP button as two classes `close no-bg` where as html button has only one `close`??

Comment: no-bg is my attempt to hide the background which nothing worked.

Comment: Asp button produces an html `input` where as other one is a button ? so they are two different elements on client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `<asp:Button>` managed control renders an `<input>` element not a `<button>` element. They can be styled differently. You can read about the differences [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/).

**Edit:** In the example you cite they use an anchor `<a>` element and style that using background images, etc. You could use a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) and style that as needed.